# GDAL convert tif to MBTILES

Tags: gdal-translate, mbtiles, gdaladdo

I have a tiff file and I'd like to convert it to mbtiles using GDAL 2.2.2, compiled with sqlite3.
The first command seems to work :

`gdal_translate -of mbtiles 000-2017-0915-6528-L93-0M20-E100.tif test.mbtiles
Input file size is 5000, 5000
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.`

Now when I try to compute overviews with gdaladdo (like in doc):

```
gdaladdo -r average test.mbtiles 2 4 8
```

`ERROR 4:`test.mbtiles' not recognized as a supported file format.`

However MBTILES is in the list of supported format in gdaladdo --formats.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure your test.mbtiles is really an mbtiles file and that it is exactly what gdal_translate created? No other software interfering? Maybe try a new filename.

Comment: How can I test if my out file is a really mbtiles file ? 
Because when I try gdalinfo test.mbtiles, I have the same error : `ERROR 4: test3.mbtiles not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'test3.mbtiles' `
`

Comment: This is very weird, because QGIS can open test3.mbtiles as a raster.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Can you share your tiff which works for you ?

Comment: Try http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/usgs/c41078a1.tif

Comment: Can you share also your mbtiles file??

Comment: Same result for : `gdaladdo -r average c41078a1.mbtiles 2 4 8
ERROR 4: "c41078a1.mbtiles" not recognized as a supported file format.
`
You can dowload my out file c41078a1.mbtiles generated by gdal_translate here: https://files.fm/u/a2hee66s

Comment: I tried your file from files.fm - worked fine. `$ gdaladdo -r average c41078a1.mbtiles 2 4 8
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
bradh@kubuntu1604:~/Downloads$ gdalinfo c41078a1.mbtiles 
Driver: MBTiles/MBTiles
Files: c41078a1.mbtiles
Size is 6489, 5117
...
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 3244x2559, 1622x1279, 811x640, 406x320, 203x160
...` What version of gdaladdo overview are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I recompiled GDAL and now it's working. Thanks